# tf.contrib.learn tutorial deprecation warning

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am just wondering what's the preferred method to refactor the code in the tf.contrib.learn [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/tflearn/) to remove the following warning in tensorflow 0.12:

```
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
```

Looking at the code, DNNClassifier cannot take a custom Estimator, and the fit method calls

```
    self._estimator.fit(x=x,
                    y=y,
                    input_fn=input_fn,
                    steps=steps,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    monitors=hooks,
                    max_steps=max_steps)
```

which triggers the warning, even if x, y and batch_size are not passed to the fit method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to "wrap" all in *SKCompat*.
I had a simile issue, and I have partially solved by (example)`tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat(tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier( ...).fit(...)`.
Otherwise you could use `input_fn()` as explained in [tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/input_fn/)

Answer (score 0):

I heard that as of Tensorflow 1.0(which will be released soon), it will be moved to main distribution as `tf.learn` from `tf.contrib.learn`. That might work if you want to give it a try.

Comment: I hope so ... I hope there is an official supported high level library.